# dropzone.js: how do i upload the thumbnail instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I can create an image thumbnail using `createImageThumbnails`.

How do I upload the thumbnail instead of the original image as the preview resizes the images well for me.